# Rails production assets pre compile not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When I run assets:precompile on my server i can clearly see that my assets are getting precompiled, also files are being written to filesystem properly, but when I visit my application from browser I am getting not found error because asset file names that are being referenced in HTML are older ones.
I am absolutely clueless about how to debug this issue. Any kind of refrence/help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "file names that are being referenced in HTML are older ones"? Appended hash values are older or the actual file names that were changed in view files are not updated?

Comment: Link of application-xx.css and application-xx.js in html file are still older ones.

Comment: Is it in production env? If so, you might have forgotten to restart your app.

Comment: @Uzbekjon. yes when i restart server it works. But i don't think it should require a restart. kindly help!

Comment: Yes. Its in production.

Comment: In production environment, you don't want rails to re-evaluate the hash of all your asset files for every single page request, do you? So, it is quite pragmatic. Let me add it as an answer for future googlers.

Comment: Hey, When i use unicorn restart it does not work but when i do unicorn stop and unicorn start it works. But if i use second approach it causes me downtime. How can i handle this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133827/discussion-between-rakesh-yadav-and-uzbekjon).

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP's comments, the app is in production environment and as such, it needed to be restarted to force the app to reevaluate the asset hashes.